# Storing solutions for data entries in a Fitness app

Tags: ios

I am currently making a fitness app for a college course in IOS programming.

I could use some tips on how I should store users' data entries in the app. The data entries will be in form of a weight amount and the date of weighing. I will use facebook login and the facebook email as user id, does anyone have some advice regarding how to connect a user with multiple amount of weight entries so I can display them when the user logs in again?

I know core data is probably what to go for but what if the user logs onto another device or gets a new device, will the entries be saved for then?

Comment: You could build a Restful  web service service and persist the entries to your local server or a cloud server such as AWS or Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a Restful web service and persist the entries to your local server or a cloud server such as [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com) or [Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us).

Answer (score 0):

For something as lightweight as this, I would just use [Parse](https://www.parse.com/) instead of spinning up an entire back end yourself.